# getmethod for retrieving source of video element

Tags: javascript, html, popcornjs

Is there a getMethod that will give me the video source so that I could set its width and height attributes from javascript.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var video = document.getElementsBySource("videos/LugaMantanah.mp4")[0];
        video.height = 300;
        video.width = 700;
        var sequence = Popcorn.sequence("container",
            [
              {
                src: "video",
                in: 0,
                out: 30
              },
              {
               src: "videos/LugaMantanahAreaCodes.mp4",
               in: 25,
               out: 55
             },
            ]);
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the width and height of the video after the event loadedmetadata fires:

```
video.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function (e) {
    var width = this.videoWidth;
    var height = this.videoHeight;
}, false );
```

---

edited after comment:

If you want to set the width of the video, you need to address the video tags (they get loaded inside the container by Popcorn).

An example to set the width and height of the first video below. You can just add it to your code after you define var sequence.

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
video.height = 150;
video.width = 100;
```

Comment: I don't want to get the width and height I want to set it.